# Angular: $rootScope variable vs event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm dealing with an app that manages users login. Like in many apps, i want to change the header when the user logs in. 
I've a main file (`index.html`) which uses `ng-include` to include the `header.html`

I found two solutions (i'm new to angular, so both may be wrong):

**1) use a $rootScope.broadcast()**

So when the user logs in I broadcast (the `auth.js`, it's inside a `factory`) a message that is intercepted by the controller in the header.

the `auth.js`

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('logged',user);
```

the `controller.js`

```
$scope.$on('logged', function(evnt, message){
      $scope.user = message;
    });
```

the `header.html`

```
<div class="header" ng-controller="GcUserCtrl as gcUserCtrl">
...
   <li><a ng-show="user" href="#">User: {{user.name}}</a></li>
```

**2) set a $rootScope variable**

As far as I understood `$rootScope` is the root of all the scope (the naming is quite smart) and all the `$scope` have access to it.

the `auth.js`

```
$rootScope.user=user;
```

the `heaeder.html` (no controller is needed here)

```
<div class="header">
...
   <li><a ng-show="user" href="#">User: {{user.name}}</a></li>
```

**Now, what's the correct way to handle it?**

- the first seems a bit more *expensive* since the broadcast may have to do many checks.
- the second .. well, I'm not a fan of global variables..

**EDIT**

**3) use service**

after the comment of alex I add this options, even if I'm not able to make it working. ([here the plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OdKbsE2bO86RkGp68ZHh?))
*it does not work without events*

`index.html`

```
...
 <ng-include src="'header.html'"></ng-include>
...
```

`header.html`

*as for the number 1)*

`controller.js`

```
.controller('GcUserCtrl', ['$scope','my.auth','$log', function ($scope, auth, $log) {
    $scope.user = auth.currentUser();
  }]);
```

`my.auth.js`

```
.factory('my.auth', ['$rootScope', '$log', function ($rootScope, $log, localStorageService) {
    var currentUser = undefined;

    return {

      login: function (user) {
        currentUser = user;
       ...

      },

  ...
      currentUser: function () {
        return currentUser;
      }
    };
  }]);
```

The problem here is that the controller is called only the first time and nothing happens after the login.

Comment: A better option would be to use a Login service [documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services). This way you can inject the service as needed by different modules.

Comment: @alex - this may be the answer...OP is looking for correct way of doing this...maybe you should flesh this out and post as answer...

Comment: i added the service, that was my first thought but i'm not able to make it working

Comment: no console errors. i put some log in the `UserCtrl` to see if it was called, and it doesnt seems so. in the `auth` i want to have some handy functions that tells me if the user is loggedIn and what's the user (plus the token that is sotred in the sessionStorage).

Comment: Don't forget to accept which ever answer you choose to be the best / most useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events are the preferred way to communicate that action needs to be taken by something else. That an action occurred that something else might be interested in action against. It also reduces scope pollution as you mentioned.

The comment about using a service in this case is only partially accurate. All of the login logic could, and should, be put into a single service specific to logging and logging out. That service would then broadcast the event when a login occurs.

```
module.service('LoginHelper', function($rootScope) {
    this.loginUser = function(username, password) {
        // on success
        $rootScope.broadcast('loggedIn', logginUserData)
    }
    this.logout = function() {
        // on success
        $rootScope.broadcast('loggedOut')
    }
})
```

The logged in data should be stored and accessible by the service.

Alternatively, $emit could be used on $rootScope. You would then only be able to watch for the 'loggedIn' event on the $rootScope by there would be marginally less overhead.

Answer (score 4):

As I stated earlier you will want to use a Service which will store the user's information. Attach user information to this service where ever you are authenticating the user. If you have questions about the best way to authenticate that would be a seperate question but you may want to look into using a Login Factory that does the actual authentication (and any authorization). You can then inject the login Service into that factory. I have created a [Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KzshMFCOZdaPB5HYAdLv?p=preview) as a reference.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.service('SessionService', function () {
  this.attachUser = function(userId, fName){
    this.userId = userId;
    this.fName = fName;
  }
});


app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, SessionService){
  // You will want to invoke attachUser some other way (perhaps on authentication), this is for test purposes only
  SessionService.attachUser(1234, 'John');

  $scope.userName = SessionService.fName; 
});
```

The code above is an example of your Service. This will act as a Session handler and store important information about the user. The controller `MainCtrl` can then invoke properties in the `SessionService` using dependency injection. The part I mentioned at the beginning of this post, `SessionService.attachUser(userId, fName)` would most likely live in a login factory.

The reason this is the best choice is because it decouples your application. It puts the session (which is really what you are storing in global variables) in a place that is designated to store that data. It makes it maintainable. You do not need to find every occurrence of $rootScope, for instance.

EDIT:
[New plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/o60Ms1sltprAqLCRdWIV?p=preview) uses rootScope broadcast/on to capture changes

Comment: i did a similar things to this, but apparently nothing happens in the header when i do `auth.login(user)`. it seems that the header controller is called only the first time. The `auth.login` is called by another controller in the page.

Comment: @EsseTi can you post it up on a Plunker

Comment: That is the issue with simple storing the values within the service. There is no notification that the value has changed, meaning a watch would need on the user name value. A watch on each value or a deep watch on an object containing all user data is excessive when an event commutates this without all of the overhead.

Comment: but where should this watch made? and is that "correct"?

Comment: As @Enzey stated you still need to capture when the data changes. I would recommend an event broadcast (example: LoggedIn / LoggedOut). The global event gets triggered from the login service. In each controller you care about, you will then add a listener for those events. In those listeners is where you do the `$scope.variable = LoginService.FName` for instance.

Comment: here it is http://plnkr.co/edit/OdKbsE2bO86RkGp68ZHh .. if i change the order of the controllers the name will be displayed.

So apparently the option **1)** is the best option.

Comment: It works because the login action resolves instantly, which would not be the cause in a real world solution.

Comment: i fixed adding the button, then it does not work as @Enzey suggested.

Comment: @alex why do you use `$rootScope.$on` rather than `$scope.$on` ? since u used a `broadcast` the `$scope` should intercept it, while if it was an `emit` it should not get catch. (i'm new to this too)

Comment: @EsseTi yes you can use $scope.$on instead. It's cleaner that way too. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

**Avoid watches**

An event would be the appropriate way to go for this kind of requirement, like how [alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774838/angular-rootscope-variable-vs-event/29775768#29775768) has pointed out. A plunk demonstrating an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/v6OXjOXZzF9McMvtn6hG?p=preview

But for this particular scenario, I don't think the **"angular way"** is the **"way"**. Given the nature of how `$broadcast` and/or `$emit` works (i.e. the default way events work in angular) I would avoid them...(Read the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on) to understand why). In short, these mechanisms are meant to trigger listeners (attached to some scope) up/down the scope heirarchy. You don't really need all that. (Ref [code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L1159) for `$emit`)

I'd normally rely on other event propagation mechanisms (considering this pattern of requirement).

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, SessionService, $document){
  // You will want to invoke attachUser some other way (perhaps on authentication), this is for test purposes only
  $scope.isLoggedIn = false;
  $document.bind('$loggedin', function(){
      $scope.isLoggedIn = true;
      $scope.user = SessionService.fName;
  });
  $scope.logout = function() {
    SessionService.attachUser(null, null);
    $scope.isLoggedIn = false;
  };
});

app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, SessionService, $document){
  $scope.doLogin = function() {
    console.log('doLogin');
    SessionService.attachUser(1234, $scope.username);  
    var doc = $document[0];
    var evt = new Event('$loggedin');
    doc.dispatchEvent(evt);
  };
});
```

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/CXnuUuE8lGH0THTZuPTH?p=preview)

Of course, when you are done with that view, always cleanup. Handle the `$destroy` event on that controller's scope and unbind the event handler...

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $document.unbind('$loggedin');
};
```

Refer [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) for more on how to trigger events using DOM.

Update: [24 Sep]

Here is a small directive setup which demonstrates the point:

```
app.directive('ngNest', function($parse, $compile, $timeout){
  var end = false;
  var level = 0;

  var fnPostLink = function(scope, element, attrs) {    
    //console.log('start:', ++fnPostLink.count);
    var lvl = attrs.level;
    if(!lvl) {
      throw 'Level not specified';
    }
    var create = document.createElement.bind(document);

    var level = parseInt(lvl);
    var count = 0;
    var div = create('div');
    div.setAttribute('ng-controller', 'DummyCtrl');
    var cls = function() {
      return 'margin ' + (count % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd');
      //return 'margin even';
    };
    div.setAttribute('class', cls());
    var node = div;
    while(count++ < level - 1) {
      var child = create('div');
      child.setAttribute('ng-controller', 'DummyCtrl');
      child.setAttribute('class', cls());
      node.appendChild(child);
      node = child;      
    }

    node.setAttribute('ng-controller', 'FinalCtrl');
    node.innerHTML = 'foo';
    var $new = $compile(div)(scope);
    var el = element;
    el.append($new);
  };

  fnPostLink.count = 0;
  var fnPreLink = function(scope, element, attrs) {    
    //console.log('prelink');    
  };

  var api = {    
    link: {
      post: fnPostLink,
      pre: fnPreLink
    },
    template: '<div></div>',
    scope: {},
    restrict: 'E',    
    replace: true
  };

  return api;

});
```

It simply nests divs attaching a controllers to it. I am attaching these two controllers:

```
app.controller('DummyCtrl', function($scope){  
});

app.controller('FinalCtrl', function($scope, $document){
  $scope.$on('$myEvt', function(){
    console.log('$myEvt', $scope.$id, new Date().getTime());
  });

  $document.bind('$myEvt', function(){
    console.log('$myEvt', $scope.$id, new Date().getTime());
  });
});
```

FinalCtrl is added to the tail; DummyCtrl is added to the rest.

In the html template I do something like:

```
<ng-nest level="10"></ng-nest>
```

There is also in the html file a nested markup which is manually put there...

Entire code may be found here: https://gist.github.com/deostroll/a9a2de04d3913f021f13

Here are the results I've obtained running from my browser:

```
Live reload enabled.
$broadcast 1443074421928
$myEvt 14 1443074421929
$myEvt 19 1443074421930
DOM 1443074426405
$myEvt 14 1443074426405
$myEvt 19 1443074426405
```

You can notice the difference in the ticks when I've done $broadcast. I have done a $broadcast on $rootScope; hence angular walks down the scope tree *depth-first* and triggers those listeners attached the respective scopes, and, *in that order*...The stuff in $emit & $broadcast source code also validates this fact.

Comment: If you are going to recommend against $broadcast and $emit in favor of standard JS eventing please include rational or a link to a write regarding this.

Comment: @Enzey updated post. Check $emit 's source to start with...you will figure it out eventually... :)

Comment: I'm sure I could figure it out but SO is about knowledge sharing. Without an explanation that comment is not very useful to others looking to understand when they should or should not use Angular eventing.

Comment: Hmm. How do I refer to that version of code out of github?

Comment: This is interesting. how much is the benefit?.. in terms of the extra code vs efficiency.

Comment: please describe why events in angular are bad.